# livePermissionBlocked error from Youtube liveBroadcast/insert API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

When attempting to call the [liveBroadcasts/insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) API I receive a livePermissionBlocked error. I have two google cloud projects, and both have been verified to be able to use auth/youtube scope. In one project with the same google user I can call that api without any issue. In the other project using the same user I receive livePermissionBlocked error. How can I investigate further why that API fails in one of the google cloud projects?

See below the full error response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The user is blocked from live streaming.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The user is blocked from live streaming.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "livePermissionBlocked",
        "extendedHelp": "https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also please note I have verified that the user I am testing with has Youtube streaming enabled. I am able to live stream on Youtube and also using one of my google cloud projects.